# Build server fails to load custom code analysis ruleset

Tags: msbuild, code-analysis, fxcop, build-server

We are using Code Analysis on our projects. As part of this we have Code Analysis enabled on the build server allowing for continious checks.

Now we are receiving this error:

> CA0063 : * Failed to load rule set file '[name].ruleset' or one of its
>   dependent rule set files.

[name] being a ruleset on our internal network, available for everyone.

Code Analysis runs perfectly fine on each local machine, but not on the build server. How can we fix this issue?

Notes:

- We use a custom made ruleset
- We are not using any custom rules (yet)

Comment: have you checked in the new ruleset? Is the path to the ruleset added to build spaces?

Comment: The ruleset is put on a network-location which the server has access to.

Comment: Any reason why you are doing it this way and not have the ruleset added onto the tfs?

Comment: The ruleset is being used by 10+ programmers and I want to be able to turn on and off any rules on the fly, without having to redistribute.

Comment: That's even more dangerous. Best way to go about doing it is to include the rules that work for everyone on TFS, perhaps in a folder shared by all projects/programmers. When a change is done, the change is only committed when the CI build runs successfully.

Comment: Do understand that all programmers use this ruleset actively through Code Analysis on build. Also through check-in with this ruleset in TFS. So I think having it on a network location is something I really want to use. Why is it dangerous?

Comment: It is dangerous because changes will be done on shared folder untracked. it's only when other people compile that they find out if a change has worked or not. If you do the change on Tfs, you have a history of changes and also the option of doing a gated builds

Comment: To answer your question, edit your csproj file and look at the property <CodeAnalysisRuleSet></CodeAnalysisRuleSet>

Change the value to mapped drive pointing to the same network folder. Make sure that in your build server, you have the same mapped drive.

Comment: I have the CodeAnalysisRuleSet tag-value edited to the network file already, which is why I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue as well. How I solved it was to add my custom ruleset into version control (Git) as a new directory within my project files. We are using Jenkins for our CI, so in my Jenkins.build I then made sure to specify the absolute file path to my ruleset on the Jenkins server, which you can get by looking at your Workspace on Jenkins. For example the path may look like :

`e:\Jenkins\workspace\SampleProj-Dev\Rulesets\CustomRules.ruleset`

In Jenkins.build file, I added an argument to the msbuild.exe program execution with:

`<arg line="/p:RunCodeAnalysis=true;CodeAnalysisRuleSet=e:\Jenkins\workspace\SampleProject-Dev\Rulesets\CustomRules.ruleset"/>`

Before I had tried using a relative path but with a build containing many sub-projects, Jenkins tried to append the path onto a changing path. This path was based on the currently building sub-project, resulting in the same error you received.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled onto a fix for this tonight for a project that has been suffering from it for ages. I created a new configuration CHECKED and the problem disappeared. Then by:

1. Deleting the existing configurations from Configuration Manger;
2. Exiting and saving (this step might not be necessary); and finally
3. Recreating the dropped configurations from the newly created one, CHECKED

the problem has now disappeared completely in all configurations.

This was all in Visual Studio 2013.